# Add coupon names and percentage to WooCommerce view order details and email notifications

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications, coupon

I used [Add the Coupon Code names to Woocommerce View Order details and email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583645/add-the-coupon-code-names-to-woocommerce-view-order-details-and-email-notificati) to  inspire my snippet.

I'm trying to expand the snippet to also include the coupon percentage amount in brackets, if the coupon type is a percentage discount.

This is what it should look like:

[image]

Here is my attempt. Any ideas if this is correct:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_coupons_codes_line_to_order_totals_lines', 10, 3 );
function add_coupons_codes_line_to_order_totals_lines( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    // Exit if there is no coupons applied
    if( sizeof( $order->get_used_coupons() ) == 0 )
        return $total_rows;

    $new_total_rows = []; // Initializing

    foreach($total_rows as $key => $total ){
        $new_total_rows[$key] = $total;

        if( $key == 'discount' ){
            // Get applied coupons
            $applied_coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();
            
        if( $applied_coupons->discount_type == 'percent'){
             // Get applied coupon percentge
            $applied_coupons_percentage = $applied_coupons->coupon_amount;
            }

            // Insert applied coupon codes in total lines after discount line
            $new_total_rows['coupon_codes'] = array(
                'label' => __('Applied coupons:', 'woocommerce'),
                'value' => implode( ', ', $applied_coupons '<p> ({$applied_coupons_percentage}%)</p>' ),
            );
        }
    }

    return $new_total_rows;
}
```

I use this to display the coupon percentage on the cart page. I tried to incorporate this into my snippet above:

```
function my_coupon_percentage_cart($value, $coupon)
{
    if($coupon->discount_type == 'percent' && !empty($coupon->coupon_amount))
    {
        $amt = "<br><br><p><em><strong>{$coupon->coupon_amount}% OFF on Your Order</strong></em></p>";   
    }

    return $value.$amt;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html','my_coupon_percentage_cart',10,2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the fact that your code contains mistakes, it also contains some outdated code

- `get_used_coupons()` is deprecated since 3.7.0 - Replaced with better named method to reflect the actual data being returned.
- `$coupon->discount_type` has been replaced with `$coupon->get_discount_type()`
- `$coupon->coupon_amount` has been replaced with `$coupon->get_amount()`

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    // Exit if there is no coupons applied
    if ( sizeof( $order->get_coupon_codes() ) == 0 ) return $total_rows;

    $new_total_rows = []; // Initializing

    foreach( $total_rows as $key => $total ) {
        $new_total_rows[$key] = $total;

        if ( $key == 'discount' ) {
            // Get used coupon codes only
            $coupon_codes = $order->get_coupon_codes();
            
            // Loop through WC_Order_Item_Coupon objects
            foreach ( $coupon_codes as $index => $coupon_code ) {
                // Get an instance of the WC_Coupon Object
                $coupon = new WC_Coupon( $coupon_code );

                // Discount type = percent & amount NOT empty
                if ( $coupon->get_discount_type() == 'percent' && ! empty ( $coupon->get_amount() ) ) {
                    $coupon_codes[$index] = $coupon_code . ' (' . $coupon->get_amount() . '%)';
                }
            }
            

            // Insert applied coupon codes in total lines after discount line
            $new_total_rows['coupon_codes'] = array(
                'label' => __( 'Applied coupons:', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value' => implode( ', ', $coupon_codes ),
            );
        }
    }

    return $new_total_rows;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'filter_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
```