# Split discount (coupon) row into multiple deducted cost rows in WooCommerce order totals table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, coupon

If there are 2 discount coupons used, it shows the sum of 2 coupons in the Woocommerce order totals table, while I want to show the deducted cost of each coupon separately.

For example, 2 coupons are inserted, currently it shows:

- coupon : $100

I want to change this to:

- coupon1(coupon code) : $50
- coupon2(coupon code) : $50

Path from the WooCommerce template file: [order-details.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php)

```php
foreach ( $order->get_order_item_totals() as $key => $total ) {
    ?>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row"><?php echo esc_html( $total['label'] ); ?></th>
            <td><?php echo ( 'payment_method' === $key ) ? esc_html( $total['value'] ) : wp_kses_post( $total['value'] ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
}
```

Any advice on how to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary to add HTML table tags via the `woocommerce_get_order_item_totals` hook, since it concerns table rows.

Next answer removes the default discount row and splits it over several rows with the desired details.

Functions used in this answer:

- [WC_Abstract_Order::get_coupon_codes()](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_abstract_orderget_coupon_codes/)
- [get_discount()](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item-Coupon.html#method_get_discount)
- [get_code()](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item-Coupon.html#method_get_code)

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    // Exit if there is no coupons applied
    if ( sizeof ( $order->get_coupon_codes() ) == 0 ) return $total_rows;
    
    // Initializing
    $new_rows = [];
    
    // Loop through order total lines
    foreach ( $total_rows as $total_key => $total_row ) {
        // Store current rows, except discount
        if ( $total_key != 'discount' ) {
            // Store
            $new_rows[$total_key] = $total_row;
        } else {            
            // For each coupon
            foreach ( $order->get_items('coupon') as $coupon ) {
                // New rows
                $new_rows[$coupon->get_code()] = array(
                    'label' => __( 'Coupon: ', 'woocommerce' ) . $coupon->get_code(),
                    'value' => wc_price( $coupon->get_discount() ),
                );
            }   
        }
    }

    // Overwrite
    $total_rows = $new_rows;

    return $total_rows;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'filter_woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );
```

---

Result:

[image: result]

---

Related: [Add coupon names and percentage to WooCommerce view order details and email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68952233/11987538)

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 10, 3);

function woocommerce_get_order_item_totals($total_rows, $order, $tax_display) {
    // Loop through order items "coupon"
    $original_dicount_value = $total_rows['discount']['value'];
    $breaked_dicount_value = '';
    $wrapp_table_start = '<table style="width:100%">';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($order->get_items('coupon') as $item_id => $item) {
        // Get the coupon array data
        $data = $item->get_data();
        $coupon_code = $data['code'];
        $coupon_amt = strip_tags(wc_price($data['discount'] + $data['discount_tax']));
        $breaked_dicount_value .= "<tr>
            <td>coupon$i($coupon_code)</td>
            <td>$coupon_amt</td>
          </tr>";
        $i++;
    }
    $wrapp_table_end = "</table>";
    $total_rows['discount']['value'] = ('' !== $breaked_dicount_value ) ? $wrapp_table_start . $breaked_dicount_value . $wrapp_table_end : $original_dicount_value;
    return $total_rows;
}
```

Comment: first of all, thank you for your response, i wanted some changes -> <th>coupon1(coupon code) :</th><td>$50</td> and <th>coupon2(coupon code) :</th><td>$50</td>,if you do not understand the question, tell me to explain more